# Webmaster Tools: root and subdirectories?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, search

We have all our international sites on our `.com` domain like this:

```
site.com/uk
site.com/us
etc...
```

When creating the sites in Webmaster Tools I've created different sites and submitted sitemaps for each directory so that we can appropriately geotarget the site.

Is it also recommended to add the root `.com` with its geotargeting set to international? If so should I also add all the seperate sitemaps (like the `/us/sitemap.xml`) even though they have been added to the directory level sites?

Answer (score 1):

A root `.com` sitemap is added to every site at once. I think in a directory site based on different geo location we have to add separate sitemaps. I had added a sitemap last week on a site and it is working fine and all the pages are indexed in Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You should have a different sitemap.xml for each sub site (uk/us/ca/de) and then have a main sitemap for your default site which does not duplicate the items in the other sitemaps.  Domics answer is 100% correct, but again make sure that you dont repeat results in your sitemap.

A word about sitemaps.  If your site is less than 100 pages dont really worry about having one.  Google and Bing have become super awesome of crawling sites without sitemaps and still getting all the results pretty darn quickly.  I now only use SiteMaps for huge sites (e-commerce) with thousands of pages.